# How to check whether the tlb file is registered in registry using C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

I have created a class library using c#.And i have registered the class library using

regasm..

```
  RegAsm.exe Discovery.dll /tlb: Discovery.dll /codebase
```

Now i want to know whether the assembly is registered or not using c++. I need because I have to check the registry for this dll if it is not registered I have to registered it 
programatically if it is registered then i simply skip it.

so How can i know whether the assembly registered or not using c++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to bother at all?  There is no harm to registering it again if it IS already there.

Answer (score 4):

Use LoadRegTypeLib to load it, and check the return value for errors. For example:

```
HRESULT hr;
ITypeLib *libraryIntf;

hr = LoadRegTypeLib(IID_GuidOfTypeLibrary, LibraryVersionMajor,
    LibraryVersionMinor, 0, &libraryIntf);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    libraryIntf->Release();
    libraryIntf = NULL;
    // Type library is registered and can be loaded.
}
else
{
    // Type library is not registered.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT:

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID contains all class IDs
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface contains all interface IDs
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib contains all type library IDs

Use the [`RegOpenKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(VS.85).aspx) function to open the key. If the key exists, the function returns success.

Comment: You have already been given that information.  Use RegOpenKeyEx() to open the "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{typelib guid foes here}" key.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the library UUID can be found in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{guid}.  By checking for that key, you know if the dll was registered.  The  [`RegGetKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724902(VS.85).aspx) may do the trick.