# Using C# to register a type library from a given .dll

Tags: c#, regasm

I've been using `System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish.RegisterAssembly('Path to assembly.dll')` to register my assembly, but I need to create a type library and register that also.

I've tried using RegisterTypeLib:

```
[DllImport("oleaut32.dll")]
static extern int RegisterTypeLib(ITypeLib ptlib, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string szFullPath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string szHelpDir);
```

like this :

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(TheAction[2]);
RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();

bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);

TypeLibConverter converter = new TypeLibConverter();
ConversionEventHandler eventHandler = new ConversionEventHandler();

ITypeLib typeLib = (ITypeLib)converter.ConvertAssemblyToTypeLib(asm, TheAction[2].Replace (".dll",".tlb"), 0, eventHandler);

RegisterTypeLib(typeLib, TheAction[2].Replace(".dll", ".tlb"), string.Empty);
```

It throws no error, so how can I check if it worked?

Also, if there is a simpler way to do this from C# I'd love to hear about it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether the tlb file is registered in registry using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147053/how-to-check-whether-the-tlb-file-is-registered-in-registry-using-c)

Comment: If the return value is less than 0 then call Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR()